# Issue while installing Redis on a Pi

Tags: redis, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm trying to install Redis on my Pi. Sames steps as explained in next link: https://redis.io/download

```
$ wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-5.0.5.tar.gz
$ tar xzf redis-5.0.5.tar.gz
$ cd redis-5.0.5
$ make
```

After a while next messages gets returned-->

```
/usr/bin/ld: networking.o: in function `createClient':
/home/pi/redis-stable/src/networking.c:109: undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_8'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:219: redis-server] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/redis-stable/src'
make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 2
```

Other approaches:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Installing redis from tar, we need the newest for Redis Stream
rm -rf /etc/redis
mkdir -p /etc/redis
cd /etc/redis
wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-5.0.3.tar.gz
tar xzf redis-5.0.3.tar.gz
cd redis-5.0.3
make cleandist
make
make install
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't run into this issue myself, but it seems that libatomic.so provides the symbol on my Raspberry Pi. So try adding -latomic to the linker flags (`LDFLAGS='-latomic'` to configure if the project uses GNU Autoconf, `-DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS='-latomic'` if it uses cmake, etc).

You may also have to install the package libatomic-ops-dev as well (if not already installed)

EDIT: Seems other people have run into this. See for example this redis bug: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/6275

Also redis seems to have it's own obscure build system. It may work to do: `make FINAL_LIBS=-latomic` or you may have to patch src/Makefile to add `-latomic` to the `FINAL_LIBS` variable

Comment: Thanks very much. Tried but no success.